# How can I pass stateProps through JSON? (Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, gatsby

I use JSON and `useStaticQuery` to pass data about links on my website. For example—

### `simBarItems.json`

```json
[
  {
    "content": "Provia",
    "url": "/foto/provia",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "content": "Velvia",
    "url": "/foto/velvia",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "content": "Astia",
    "url": "/foto/astia",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "content": "Classic Chrome",
    "url": "/foto/classic-chrome",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "content": "Acros",
    "url": "/foto/acros",
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "content": "PRO Neg.",
    "url": "/foto/pro-neg",
    "id": 6
  }
]
```

### `SimBar.jsx`

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link, useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { container } from "./SimBar.module.scss"

function isActive({ isCurrent }) {
  return isCurrent ? { className: "active" } : {}
}

function isPartiallyActive({ isPartiallyCurrent }) {
  return isPartiallyCurrent ? { className: "active" } : {}
}

export default function SimBar() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allSimBarItemsJson {
        nodes {
          id
          content
          url
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  let items = data.allSimBarItemsJson.nodes

  return (
    <nav className={container}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/foto" getProps={isActive}>
            Alle foto
          </Link>
        </li>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <Link to={item.url} getProps={isPartiallyActive}>
              {item.content}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

As you can see, most items should have the same `stateProp`, so they can go in the same `map`. However, the first item should have a different `stateProp`.

My question is: How can I pass the `stateProp` through JSON so that I can include the item with the `isActive` link in the `map`? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your JSON data, you have a few options (at least):

- Modify directly the JSON to add the `isActive` attribute only in the first element
- Tweak your data directly in the component

  - Before the loop:

    ```
     let items = data.allSimBarItemsJson.nodes
     items[0].isActive=true
    ```

    So now your first item has the attribute active so when you loop you can access to it:

    ```
      {items.map(item => {
        console.log("has isActive attribute: ", item.isActive)
        return <li key={item.id}>
          <Link to={item.url} getProps={isPartiallyActive}>
            {item.content}
          </Link>
        </li>
      })}
    ```
  - Using the index to determine which one is the first, hence `isActive`, on the fly:

    ```
    {items.map((item, index) => {
       console.log("has active attribute: ", index===0)
       return <li key={item.id}>
         <Link to={item.url} getProps={isPartiallyActive}>
           {item.content}
         </Link>
       </li>
     })}
    ```

    As you can see in the docs, the [`map` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as a second argument takes the `index` so you can access to the first position at any time (`index===0`).

Each implementation will be more optimal depending on what you want to achieve with the `isActive` (i.e: if it needs to change between `items` or not).